# Clustering Microservices Components

Tags: cluster-computing, microservices

I have a Microservice that is realised as a Play framework based HTTP service. We now want to add fault tolerance to this service by having another instance that picks up the requests when one instance goes down. Now I understand that Microservices are not designed from the ground up to be clustered as they are purely stateless, self sustaining components that are meant to simply run.

Are there ways wherein I could add failover support? I'm thinking of some external component that checks for the status of the service and reacts upon failures by starting another instance on some other host. Any suggestions?

Comment: Would wrapping my Microservices as docker container and managing the docker containers using a tool like Kubernetes work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, there is a `discovery service` where the services can register theirselves. If a service needs to communicate with another service, it requests instances of these service at the discovery service and most of the time there is client-side load balancing as well.

I've also used `Hystrix` to wrap HTTP calls to handle failure.

I'm not familiar with building microservices with the `Play framework`, but when using `Spring` I've used:

- Netflix Eureka - as the discovery service
- Hystrix - To handle HTTP failures / timeouts when services go down
- Ribbon - Client side load-balancing

A blog series that provides an example using the full stack is [this one](http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2015/05/20/blog-series-building-microservices/). However, it is using `Spring` but I guess it can be helpful either way.

Comment: We are not talking about EJB like services where it makes sense to get hold of an instance of a service by looking up a registry. What we have is a collection of Play framework applications where the API is exposed as a REST endpoint.

Comment: I'm not talking about EJB either, I'm talking about completely separated microservice. E.g. play application 1 containing a Product service (with its own API), and a 2nd application containing a Billing service (also with it's own API). These can be deployed seperately on 2 server and register theirselves at the discovery service (which is also completely separated)